# How can I navigate between files in visual studio code with cmd?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I navigate between files just like in browser by pressing `cmd + 1` or `cmd + 2` ?

[image]

Comment: search key binding GUI for `index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added the shortcut in vscode inside `Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts > workbench.action.openeditoratindex`

[image]